# Missing SQL Server Management Studio in SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-express

I have just downloaded SQL Server 2014 Express. In the setup client included, I chose "New SQL Server stand-alone installation or ...". I just left everything as default.

However, at the end of the installation, I cannot find SQL Server Management Studio on my machine?

I have check the installation setting and there is no explicit setting (feature selection) to include SQL Server Management Studio?

I am using windows 8.

How can I get SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install that separately. It isn't a part of the default SQL Server Express package.

See [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSQLServerExpress.aspx):

- [SQL Management Studio x64](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/A/E/EAE6F7FC-767A-4038-A954-49B8B05D04EB/MgmtStudio%2064BIT/SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe)
- [SQL Management Studio x86](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/A/E/EAE6F7FC-767A-4038-A954-49B8B05D04EB/MgmtStudio%2032BIT/SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe)

Comment: Thanks! I am downloading it now...So, does that mean ssms will work w/o me first downloading and installing the sql server?

Comment: Yes. Can you run that on machines without SQL Server too. (That was the entire point of a separate package)